# Error en PIL, image index out of range, python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Muy buenas, quisiera que me aclarasen una duda. Creando una función que a partir de una imagen en "L" me cree una matrix con los valores de sus píxeles, me devuelve esto:

> return self.im.getpixel(xy), IndexError: image index out of range

Si alguien me puede responder, le estaría muy agradecido, pues llevo horas y horas y horas con esto.

El código:

```
from PIL import Image

def datalize(img):
    x, y = img.size
    datrix = []

    for e in xrange(x):
        datrix.append([])
            for m in xrange(y):
                delta = img.getpixel((x,y))
                delta = int(delta)
                datrix[e].append(delta)
    return datrix
```

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: he editado el código pero no sé si está correcto porque no has indentado nada y no sé dónde empiezan y acaban los bucles.

Comment: `img.getpixel((x,y))` <-- no deberías usar `(e,m)` ??

Comment: Seeep, ya rula, muchñisimas gracias. Gracias también por el edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la línea en la que obtienes `delta` por primera vez estás usando `(x,y)` y creo que debería ser `(e,m)`.

Si tu imagen tiene, por ejemplo, 1000 x 500 píxeles (x = 1000, y = 500) cuando indexas, en Python, la indexación comienza por 0 y, por tanto, podrías indexar la `x` desde 0 hasta 999 y la `y` desde 0 a 499, al usar `x=1000` e `y=500` (`x` e `y` los obtienes de `img.size`, yo uso unos valores hipotéticos) te estás pasando de índice y es por ello que te devuelve el `IndexError`